# Regex fix for GSuite content compliance

Tags: regex, email, google-workspace

I have a regex that I am trying to check for phishing emails.

**The emails come in like:**

```
Principal-joe smith <officeemailxyz@gmail.com>
```

I need to identify any email that has
`principal*@gmail.com` or `@hotmail.com` or `@yahoo.com`.

**This is my regex:**

```
(\W|^)(?i)pr[i!1]nc[i!1]p[a@]l@(yahoo|hotmail|gmail)\.com(\W|$)

(\W|^)(?i)pr[i!1]nc[i!1]p[a@]l---WHAT DOES HERE---@(yahoo|hotmail|gmail)\.com(\W|$)
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you have to make the search case insensitive with the option `/i`.
Than, you should include any email-address-valid character plus the space, if I understand your example correctly.
I ran a couples of tests and the following seems to catch all cases.

`/^[\w\s]*principal[\<+\s*a-zA-Z0-9._-]*?@[yahoo|hotmail|gmail]*\.com[\>]?$/gmi`